# django query left join, sum and group by

Tags: django, orm

I have a model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Sales(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

How do I return data as the following sql query (annotate sales with product name, group by product, day and month, and calculate sum of sales):

```
select p.name
    , extract(day from date) as day
    , extract(month from date) as month
    , sum(s.price)
from timetracker.main_sales s
left join timetracker.main_product p on p.id = s.product_id_id
group by month, day, p.name;
```

Thanks,
If only ORM was as simple as sql... Spent several hours trying to figuring it out...

PS. Why when executing Sales.objects.raw(sql) with sql query above I get "Raw query must include the primary key"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay, ExtractMonth

Product.objects.values(
    'name',
    month=ExtractDay('products__date')
    day=ExtractDay('products__date'),
).annotate(
    total_price=Sum('products__price')
).order_by('name', 'month', 'day')
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `product`, instead of <s>`product_id`</s>.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Product` model to the `Sales`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`products`</s> relation to `sales`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Is there a way go get the info the opposite way? going from sales object. Seems kind of unusual way go do it. Also, products that are never sold will be in results.

Comment: @ilya: well that is what a `left join` is intended to do: include results that have never been sold as well. Although ghere because of the `ExtractDay`, etc. that will be omitted.

Comment: You can use `Sale.objects.values('product_id__name', ...)` where for the functions, you thus drop the ``products__` prefix.